# MVP работа с двумя и более презентерами

Tags: android, activity, mvp

Пишу приложение используя паттерн MVP, т.к. хочу на практике понять, что как в этом паттерне работает.
У меня есть activity с начальными настройками. И после того как пользователь всё введёт, нужно переходить на второе activity. Так вот, пользователь ввёл все данные. По идее нужно через презентер создать модель и при запуске новой activity передать, либо саму модель, что неправильно, либо ссылку на неё. Вот вопрос как это сделать.

1. сохранять модель в Application
2. передавать модель от одного презентера к другому
3. записывать состояние модели в файл/бд и при запуске второй activity, её презентером считывать данные.

Мне кажется что, более верным с точки зрения MVP является второй вариант. Но тут тоже есть вопросы. Первый презентер должен создать второй презентер, передать ему модель и параллельно первое activity должно через intent запустить второе activity. Не могу понять, как реализовать присоединение второго презентера к activity. 
В итоге два вопроса, какой вариант лучше с точки зрения MVP? И как реализовать присоединение созданного презентера к созданному activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать следующую схему для сохранения объектов и получением их в других презентерах. Для этого необходимо иметь репозиторий (он будет отвечать за сохранение/получение данных).

В вашем случае можно сохранить настройки в репозиторий, например, с помощью метода репозиятория `setSettings(Settings settings)` (внутри репозиторий сам решает, куда ему сохранить объект - в БД, оставить где-то у себя в поле или какой-то другой способ). Затем в другом презентере попросить у репозитория сохраненные настройки, например, с помощью метода `getSettings()`.

[image: Схема передачи объектов между разными презентерами]

Репозиторий в презентер можно добавлять через инъекции зависимостей через конструктор (рекомендую почитать про DI и про Dagger 2)

Если необходимо передать ID записи (например id чата), то я передаю через аргументы во фрагменте/активити, а затем вызываю необходимый метод в презентере с переданным аргументом. Ниже пример кода.

```
//MainActivity
...
private openSecondActivity() {
    startActivity(SecondActivity.newIntent(this, "idididid");
}
...

//SecondActivity
...
private static final String EXTRA_ID = "key_for_id";
public static Intent newIntent(Context context, String id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
    return i;
}
...
public void loadInfo() {
    presenter.loadInfo(getIntent().getExtraString(EXTRA_ID));
}
...
```